Android Studio debugging off
Something happened with my Android Studio.
Till now when I click debugging, showed a debugging window at the bottom, and I could see the values of the variables.
Now no debugging window, and not showing the values.
"Step over" and other button are gray. Only "pause" active. If I pause "MessageQeue.java" opening.
I can turn on the debugging window, but every time I have to turn it on. And I cannot turn on the values.
Can someone help me please what should I have to do?
Here is a video about the problem:
text
Fully uninstall the Android Studio.
Download the newest and install
Did not help.

What Android Studio version do you use?
